# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished error in Rails set-up on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, activerecord

I am trying to debug an application using `Ruby on Rails`(3.0.8) setup in `Ubuntu` using `RubyMine`.My application is without a database.

But when i start the server i am getting an error:-

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

This is the full trace of the error:-

```
ctiverecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:170:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:144:in `connection'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__515326265__call__889079158__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:1484:in `event_callback'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:544:in `block in eventable_read'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:542:in `times'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:542:in `eventable_read'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:201:in `eventable_read'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:369:in `block in crank_selectables'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:369:in `each'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:369:in `crank_selectables'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:324:in `block in run'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:318:in `loop'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:318:in `run'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:62:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have not installed `MySql` Gem in my Gemfile

When I start the same application on another machine(My Senior's) it seems to work.The code seems to be same.I tried various sites for the solution but it does not seem to help..

Can someone please help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `rails 3.2.12`
Comment `require 'rails/all'` in /config/application.rb
and add these in the same file

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

also comment

```
#config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

Now in config/environments/development.rb
comment these lines

```
#config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
#config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
```

Check my commit on [github](https://github.com/sagarjunnarkar/http_header_dom/commit/0357bcc281c1a2ba524b4a3515186b839426006a) when I got same error.